# Fill out this derivation..

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm having immense trouble trying to fill out the blanks in this proof.

> $\newcommand{\tofrom}{\leftrightarrow}
> \boxed{\begin{array}{l|l:l}
> 1. & (A\tofrom \neg B) & \text{Premise}
> \\ 2. & (C\to (\neg\neg D \wedge E)) & \text{Premise}
> \\ 3. & \neg B & \text{Premise}
> \\\hline 4. &  & \text{Assumption}
> \\  5. &  & \tofrom\text{ Elimination }1,3
> \\  6. &  & \to\text{ Elimination }2, 4
> \\ 7. &  & \wedge\text{ Elimination }6
> \\ \hline 8. &  & \text{Assumption}
> \\  9. &  & \neg \text{ Introduction } 7, 8
> \\ \hline 10. &  & \neg\text{ Elimination } 9
> \\  11. &  & \vee \text{ Introduction } 10
> \\  12. &  & \wedge \text { Introduction } 11, 5
> \\ \hline 13. & C \to ((D\vee H)\wedge A) & \to\text{ Introduction } 12
> \end{array} }$

[Click the blue text. It is an image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bPUh.jpg)

Comment: Click the blue text.. it's a link to the image. @Dylan

Comment: MathJaxed Text is preferred over offsite images. @sefor

Comment: @Andres Caicedo awesome table, sir :).

Answer (score 1):

Assume [a] : $C$

From 1) and 3) derive : $A$

From 2) and $C$ derive : $\lnot \lnot D \land E$

From $\lnot \lnot D \land E$ derive $\lnot \lnot D$ by $\land$-elim

Assume [b] : $\lnot D$

Derive a contradiction : $\bot$

Derive : $D$ from the contradiction, discharging assumption [b]

Derive : $D \lor H$ by $\lor$-intro

Derive : $(D \lor H) \land A$ by $\land$-intro

> Conclude with : $C \to [(D \lor H) \land A]$ by $\to$-intro, discharging [a].

Answer (score 0):

Work backwards.

For instance, step 13 is $\to$ introduction.  This will be discharging the assumption of the indented block. We have $C\to\ldots$ in line 13, so $C$ is the assumption of line 4, and the consequence of the implication is line 12.

This in turn allows you to suspect that $D\vee H$ and $A$ were $\wedge$ introduced from line 11 or 5.  But which was which.  Well, 11 is a $\vee$ introduction and only one term has a $\vee$.  Also line 5 is a $\tofrom$ elimination from lines 1 and 3, and you should be able to see which term that will be.

$\newcommand{\tofrom}{\mathop{\leftrightarrow}}
\boxed{\begin{array}{l|l:l}
1. & (A\tofrom \neg B) & \text{Premise}
\\ 2. & (C\to (\neg\neg D \wedge E)) & \text{Premise}
\\ 3. & \neg B & \text{Premise}
\\\hline \quad 4. & \color{red}{C} & \text{Assumption}
\\ \quad 5. & \color{blue}{A} & \tofrom\text{ Elimination }1,3
\\ \quad 6. &  & \to\text{ Elimination }2, 4
\\ \quad 7. &  & \wedge\text{ Elimination }6
\\ \hline \qquad 8. &  & \text{Assumption}
\\ \qquad 9. &  & \neg \text{ Introduction } 7, 8
\\ \hline \quad 10. &  & \neg\text{ Elimination } 9
\\ \quad 11. & \color{blue}{D\vee H}  & \vee \text{ Introduction } 10
\\ \quad 12. & \color{red}{(D\vee H)\wedge A} & \wedge \text { Introduction } 11, 5
\\ \hline 13. & C \to ((D\vee H)\wedge A) & \to\text{ Introduction } 12
\end{array} }$

And so forth.

Answer (score 0):

When you make an assumption, you're going to want to discharge it.  You'll probably assume something to do one of the following:

1. Derive a conditional.  In this case you introduce an assumption and then discharge it into a formula.
2. Deduce a negation.  In this case you assume the negated formula *without* the negation.
3. Get to a positive formula, or in other words a formula that does not have a negation symbol as it's principal connective.  In this case, you'll assume the negation of the formula that you want to find.

Now, you're trying to deduce a conditional.  So, you'll probably want to start by assuming the antecedent.  Thus, what would step 4 make sense as?

For the steps that aren't assumptions, take a look at the rules of inference and make substitutions for all instances of a particular meta-variable throughout the rule *according to what gets suggested on the right hand side.  And make sure to use fully parenthesized formulas when substituting (or switch to Polish/Reverse Polish notation).

For example, let's say I wrote the following outline trying to prove $\vdash$ ((P $\land$ Q) $\rightarrow$ (Q $\land$ P)):

```
1.        assumption
2.        1 conjunction elimination-left
3.        1 conjunction elimination-right
4.        3, 2 conjunction introduction
5.        1-4 conditional introduction
```

By the first part above, 1. follows as (P $\land$ Q).  The conjunction elimination-left rule says:

($\alpha$ $\land$ $\beta$) $\vdash$ $\alpha$

Thus, substituting P for $\alpha$ and Q for $\beta$ in the conjunction elimination left rule we have:

(P $\land$ Q) $\vdash$ P

Thus, step 2. is P.

The conjunction-elimination right rule says

($\alpha$ $\land$ $\beta$) $\vdash$ $\beta$

By a similar argument to the above, step 3 is Q.

The conjunction introduction rule says $\alpha$, $\beta$ $\vdash$ ($\alpha$ $\land$ $\beta$)

Uniformly substituting Q for $\alpha$ and P for $\beta$ thus we have

Q, P $\vdash$ (Q $\land$ P).

Thus, step 4. comes as (Q $\land$ P).

Finally, we discharge the assumption and deduce $\vdash$ ((P $\land$ Q) $\rightarrow$ (Q $\land$ P))

Now your system doesn't have a conjunction elimination left rule and a conjunction elimination right rule.  However, the conjunction rule that you have probably comes as equivalent to having both rules.  Similarly, *some* other rules might get broken down this way.

Hopeful with that in mind you'll have the ability to solve similar sorts of problems in the future.